# $(...).selectpicker is not a function angular

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to use bootstrap select on the angular project. And seems that some components, that are working with this kind of function are not working at all.
My **package.json:**
`

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.4.5",
        "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.30.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.17",
        "d3": "6.7.0",
        "dagre": "^0.8.5",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "moment": "^2.26.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "5.1.2",
        "remixicon": "^2.5.0",
        "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.4",
        "@angular/cli": "~14.2.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "typescript": "~4.7.2"
    }
```

`My angular part of code is simple, I am just trying to find some components by jQuery and inject a button inside this component, like this:`

```
constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private el: ElementRef,
        private layoutService: InternalMarketLayoutService
    ) {
        super(injector);
        this.actions = [
            new ActionItem(
                '',
                () =>
                    (<any>$('#' + this.id + this.extId)).selectpicker('toggle'),
                'ri-arrow-down-s-line',
                'PRIMARY',
                [],
                false,
                ''
            ),
        ];
    }
```

`

But still, it`s not working. And I have some errors, related to this part of the code, like this:

**ERROR TypeError: Lm(...).selectpicker is not a function**

It seems that the jQuery selector is working fine because on debug session I can see the element parameters and properties. I think, that some libraries or other modules can overwrite bootstrap-select functions.

Comment: It’s really not a good idea to combine jQuery with Angular. The lifecycles do not match.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it`s not my choice, and I must deal with this problem anyway